# How to add expressions to a Binary Quadratic Model, similar to CQM?

Tags: d-wave, qubo

In a constrained quadratic model, we are able to create expressions like this:

```python
import dimod 
my_cqm = ConstrainedQuadraticModel() 
my_cqm.q=dimod.Binary('q') 
my_cqm.p=dimod.Real('p') 
my_cqm.add_constraint(my_cqm.p<=0)
```

But for a binary quadratic model, I understand the problem must be unconstrained.  However, it doesn't seem that easy to create expressions.  In the example of [Constrained Scheduling](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/stable/examples/scheduling.html) it shows this:

```python
from dimod import BinaryQuadraticModel
bqm = BinaryQuadraticModel({'t': 1, 'v': 1, 'l': -1},
                           {'tv': -2, 'tl': 1, 'tp': -1},
                           1,
                           'BINARY')
```

To me, this seems much less convenient to create expressions than CQM. Is there an easier way to create expressions?